# How to verify an author of product?

Tags: commerce

Trying to get non-object error appears. What must be changed or added to the code in order to give the license access to the author of product?

```
function commerce_license_access($product, $op, $license = NULL, $account = NULL) {
  if (!isset($account)) {
    $account = $GLOBALS['user'];
  }

  if(commerce_product_current_user_is_author($product->uid)) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  ...
}
  ...
function commerce_product_current_user_is_author($pid1) {
  global $user;
  if ($pid1 == $user->uid) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Original code (without $product) is in http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_license/tree/commerce_license.module?id=da6e1bf7320513883f0e681ec3f4acaf974e6b10

Comment: `if ($pid == $user->uid) {` what you're checking here is if the product id is equal to the user id, which does not make sense.

Comment: I am not strong in PHP. $product->uid is passed, isn't it? $pid is just the temporary name (for $product->uid) There is a problem with $product which is not recognized as object. This code is in commerce_license.module (http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_license/tree/commerce_license.module?id=da6e1bf7320513883f0e681ec3f4acaf974e6b10)

Comment: It is true even if it is used $product in the parentheses     function commerce_license_access($product, $op, $license = NULL, $account = NULL) {

Comment: It looks like you're trying to hack the commerce license module to get this to happen. You need to rethink your approach; just adding $product to the function arguments will not change the functions calling commerce_license_access; and you're going to break how the module uses that function.

Comment: Now I see the problem, thank you. $product may not be in other functions which are more privileged but I could only find commerce_license_entity_info (). It means that $product can be passed (?). Hook_file_download_access doesn't work because of this function (maybe), so yes, I have to try making it work by hacking the module, if there are no other solutions. I suppose that a user has to have a full access to license because clearly the admin can see any files with right permissions.